# Morley center vs incenter of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Recall that the incenter of $\,$$\Delta$$ABC$ $\,$is the center of its incircle and is located at the intersection of the angle bisectors of $\,$$\Delta$$ABC$$\,$.
Morley showed that intersecting adjacent trisectors of $\,$$\Delta$$ABC$$\,$ yields an equilateral triangle (the Morley triangle) inside $\,$$\Delta$$ABC$
$\,$.  $\;$Define the Morley center of $\,$$\Delta$$ABC$$\,$$\,$to be the center of its Morley triangle.

The definitions above as well as a little experimentation suggest that both
of the following should be true.  Are there simple proofs for either?$\;$ Thanks.

Questions: $\,$1) Does the Morley center lie inside the incircle?
  
$\qquad$$\qquad$  $\,$  2) Does the incenter lie inside the Morley triangle?

Answer (score 2):

The vertices of the Morley's equilateral triangle have trilinear coordinates given by
$$ M_A = \left[1,2\cos\frac{C}{3},2\cos\frac{B}{3}\right],\quad M_B=\left[2\cos\frac{C}{3},1,2\cos\frac{A}{3}\right],\quad M_C=\left[2\cos\frac{B}{3},2\cos\frac{A}{3},1\right]$$
where $2\cos\frac{x}{3}\in (1,2)$ for any $x\in\{A,B,C\}$. Since the trilinear coordinates of the incenter are given by $I=[1,1,1]$, it follows that the incenter always lies inside $M_A,M_B,M_C$.

The trilinear coordinates of the Morley centre $X(356)$ are given by:
$$ X(356)=\left[\cos\frac{A}{3}+2\cos\frac{B}{3}\cos\frac{C}{3},\ldots,\ldots\right]$$
but these numbers always lie in the interval $\left(2,1+\cos\frac{\pi}{9}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}=2.705737\ldots\right)$, hence the Morley centre always lies inside the incircle, too.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.  Can you elaborate a little on say the first part?  Given the trilinear coordinates and inequalities you mentioned,

Comment: (cont'd) the vertices M(A), M(B), and M(C) are restricted to certain subsets of ABC but why is that enough to conclude that the incenter is necessarily included inside their convex hull?

Comment: @user2052: because you may switch from trilinear coordinates to barycentric coordinates, then explicitly compute the squared distance between the incenter and the Morley centre in terms of $r,A,B,C$, and check it is $\leq r^2$.